# Selenium XPATH how to select checkbox from a table where name is in column 2 and name in column 4

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a HTML table with some rows and columns.  I would like to select the **checkbox** where there is the **text "Name" in column 2** and the **text "crm" is in column 4**

The sample HTML is:

```
<table id="data_configuration_mappings_ct_fields_body" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
<colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr class="GJPPK2LBFG GJPPK2LBMG GJPPK2LBPG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0">
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBHG GJPPK2LBNG GJPPK2LBAH">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-388" style="outline-style:none;">
            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBNG GJPPK2LBOG GJPPK2LBAH">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-389" style="outline-style:none;" tabindex="0">
            <span class="linkhover" title="Name"
                  style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">Name</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBNG GJPPK2LBAH">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-390" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="" title="Name"
                  style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">Name</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBNG GJPPK2LBAH">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-391" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="" title="crm"
                  style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">crm</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBNG GJPPK2LBAH">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-392" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="" title="Main"
                  style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">Main</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBNG GJPPK2LBAH">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-393" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="" title="TITLE + FNAME + SNAME + GENDER"
                  style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">TITLE + FNAME + SNAME + GENDER</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBNG GJPPK2LBAH">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-394" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="" title="CRM"
                  style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">CRM</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBNG GJPPK2LBAH">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-395" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="" title="DM"
                  style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">DM</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBBH GJPPK2LBNG GJPPK2LBAH">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-396" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="" title=""
                  style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;"/>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="GJPPK2LBEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="1">
<tr class="GJPPK2LBFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="2">
<tr class="GJPPK2LBEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="3">
<tr class="GJPPK2LBFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="4">
<tr class="GJPPK2LBEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="5">
<tr class="GJPPK2LBFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="6">
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBHG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-388" style="outline-style:none;">
            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-389" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="linkhover" title="Name"
                  style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">Name</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-390" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="" title="Name"
                  style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">Name</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-391" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="" title="crm2"
                  style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">crm2</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-392" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="" title="Main"
                  style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">Main</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-393" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="" title="TITLE + FNAME + SNAME"
                  style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">TITLE + FNAME + SNAME</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-394" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="" title="CRM"
                  style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">CRM</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-395" style="outline-style:none;">
            <span class="" title="DM"
                  style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">DM</span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBBH">
</tr>
<tr class="GJPPK2LBEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="7">
<tr class="GJPPK2LBFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="8">
<tr class="GJPPK2LBEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="9">
<tr class="GJPPK2LBFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="10">
<tr class="GJPPK2LBEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="11">
<tr class="GJPPK2LBFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="12">
<tr class="GJPPK2LBEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="13">
</tbody>
```

To start off with I can get the column 2 highlighted in Xpath checker in Firefox with the following Xpath:

```
//table[@id="data_configuration_mappings_ct_fields_body"]//tr//td[2]
```

I do not know how to proceed and get the text Name from column 2 and the text crm from column 4

I can get the text Name from column 1 using the following XPath.  How do i also include the text crm from column 4?

```
//table[@id="data_configuration_mappings_ct_fields_body"]//tr//td[2]//span[text()="Name"]
```

I need some help please.

Thanks, Riaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Name" text is inside the span, to identify it you can use below `xpath`:-

```
//tr[td[2]//.='Name' and td[4]//.='crm']/td//input[@type='checkbox']
```

OR

```
//tr[td[2]//text()='Name' and td[4]//text()='crm']/td//input[@type='checkbox']
```

Comment: I would also like to include the text "crm" so i can get the right row as there are other rows in the table with the text Name

Answer (score 1):

```
//table[@id='data_configuration_mappings_ct_fields_body']
//tr[td[2]//*[.='Name']][td[4]//*[.='crm']]
//input[@type='checkbox']
```

Or, if you know for sure that the checkbox is always in column #1:

```
//table[@id='data_configuration_mappings_ct_fields_body']
//tr[td[2]//*[.='Name']][td[4]//*[.='crm']]
/td[1]//input[@type='checkbox']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an XPath to get the checkbox where there is the text "Name" in column 2 and the text "crm" is in column 4:

```
"id('data_configuration_mappings_ct_fields_body')//tr[td[2]//.='Name' and td[4]//.='crm']//input[@type='checkbox']"
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi please try this it will help also please note sample example is in java not in python

```
// take everything in the list as we are working in the table 
// and in  table number of rows for every column will be fixed

    // for column = name 2nd column xpath is
    List<WebElement> column2 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='linkhover']"));
    // for column = crm 4th column xpath is
    List<WebElement> column4 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@__gwt_cell='cell-gwt-uid-391']"));

    // for checkbox column 1 xpath is
    List<WebElement> column1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@__gwt_cell='cell-gwt-uid-388']/input"));

    // please note that no of rows for a table will always remain same 
    // for all columns in the table so 
    // so if column2 contains 5 rows then column1 and column2 will alos have no of rows = 5

    for(int i=0;i<column2.size();i++){
        // printing the value to verify that we are going in correct way
        // that is if column2 = Name then only go inside if 
        System.out.println("Column 2 Value is : " + column2.get(i).getText());
        if(column2.get(i).getText().equals("Name")){
            for(int j=0;j<column4.size();j++){
                // printing the value to verify that we are going in correct way
                // that is if column4 = crm then only go inside if 
                System.out.println("Column 4 value is : " + column4.get(j).getText());
                if(column4.get(j).getText().equals("crm")){
                    // now we are here sure that if column values are name and crm
                       // then we can perform the click on the check box
                      column1.get(i).click(); // selects first check box
                       break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
```

Hope this will give you a fair idea how to do it in python